# How to implement carousel to existing slideshow gallery with light-box using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, carousel, gallery, slideshow

I am trying to create slide gallery similar to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow_gallery.asp when user click on big  main img --> img will be open in lightbox https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/
everything is working fine except I would like to display only 4 images in row below main img (because sometimes gallery has 10+ imgs and it doesn`t look nice when all imgs are display in one line) I can hide all imgs except first 4 in css to get correct design but I am loosing functionality. My idea is to add somehow corousel, If img 5 is selected / displayed as a main img this img has to be included also in a row between 4 imgs (they are static now and only first 4 images are display)

there is .volt

```
<div id="lightgallery2" class="container gallery lightgallery">
  
  <!-- Full-width images -->
    {% for i in 0..9 %}
        <div class="gallery-item"  data-src="{{ pathToImg[i] }}">
           <img src="{{ pathToImg[i] }}" alt="{{ imgDescription }}" />
        </div>
    {% endfor  %}

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  <!-- Row images -->
  <div class="row">
    {% for i in 0..9 %}
        <div class="column-img">
            <img class="resort-img" src="{{ pathToImg[i] }}" onclick="currentSlide({{i + 1 }})" alt="{{ imgDescription }}" />
        </div>
    {% endfor  %}
  </div>

</div>
```

.less

```
    .gallery{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: relative;

        .gallery-item {
            display: none;
            
            img{
                width: 100%;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        }

        /* Next & previous buttons */
        .prev,
        .next {
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            width: auto;
            padding: 16px;
            margin-top: -50px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            
            &:hover{
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }

        .next {
            right: 0;
            border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        }

        //row images
        .row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 100%;
        }
            
        .column-img{
            display: none;

            img{
                opacity: 0.6;
                cursor: pointer;
                width: 100%;
                height: 90px;

                &:hover{
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        }

        .column-img:nth-child(-n+4){
            display:block;
            margin: 5px 0 0 ;

            .active {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

.js

```
   let slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        let i;
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-item");
        let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("resort-img");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

        //TO DO Carousel is not displaying relevant imgs  
        // if(n == 4){
        //   let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.column-img:nth-child(-n+4)');
        //   for (const element of elements) {
        //     element.style.display = 'none';
        //     }
        //     elements = document.querySelectorAll('.column-img:nth-child(n+5)');
        //     for (const element of elements) {
        //     element.style.display = 'block';
        //     }
        // }
    }
```

My idea would be:
when user get to img with index 3 I hide with js first img and display 2-5,
when user get to img with index 4 I hide with js first img and display 3-6,
when user get to img with index 5 I hide with js first img and display 4-7,
...

I start to implement that idea (that is what is commented) but it will work only in one direction forward, when user decide to click on previous it will not work anymore...
I think my way of thinking is not correct =(
I can`t use any library for that, it has to be vanilla js.
I will be very thankful for any ideas

Comment: If you only want to display 4 images then why does your template code always generate 10?  See: [Volt Template Engine](https://phalcon-php-framework-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/volt.html#for)

Comment: because I want to have all of them in lightbox, If I limit it to 4 I will have only 4

Comment: I was able to make this work by reading the [lightGallery documentation](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lg-v2/docs/getting-started/) and looking at their examples. You can customize the thumbnail list any way you want.  Suggest updating your question to include minimum code needed to replicate the problem. Questions, like this one, that require excessive work to replicate the problem usually go unanswered.